# Grammar tenses in the past

Tags: grammar

It's ages since I've spoken English.
It's ages since I spoke English.

Which past tense is correct, Present Perfect or Past Simple?

Comment: You can use either one.

Answer (score 1):

As Kate says, both are fine. Which you would use would probably depend on what you intended to say.

You are more likely to use the first as it stands, without adding anything to inform the reader more about the circumstances.

All you're saying is that it's just a long time since you last used the language.

But the second is more likely if you modify it slightly and/or add something about the circumstances:

**It's ages since I (last) spoke English to anyone here in Rome.**

In short, it's a matter of preference, not of grammar.